# how to call a function after appending it in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am appending a div using ajax and alnog with that div a function (it's a time ago function) the function needs to be called as soon as the div is appended I've tried all possible solutions but none works

my function (located in processor.php page)

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.post_the_stat').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addition_life_text.php",
        data: 'final_text='+ fin_text +'&priv='+ priv + '&post_time='+post_time ,
        success: function(data) {
                 $(".main_container").prepend(data);
                                }

          })
    })
 })
 </script>
```

the function

```
<script>
function ago()
{
  //codeblock
} 
</script>
```

my question:how do i call the function `ago` as soon as the ajax was success is appended.ive tried `window.onLoad` etc...

Comment: Just call it in your success function. If you tried that, please show what is in this function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.post_the_stat').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addition_life_text.php",
        data: 'final_text='+ fin_text +'&priv='+ priv + '&post_time='+post_time ,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".main_container").prepend(data);
            ago();
        }

     })
    })
 })
 </script>
```

Please try above. Hopefully this will work

Comment: Just write next to 'ago()' OR It's also depends on function flow than you need to use callback

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 success: function(data) {
             $(".main_container").prepend(data).go();
                            }

      })
```